# How to make Jenkins execute pipeline steps from the remote root directory?

Tags: jenkins, path, jenkins-pipeline, filepath

I created a simple pipline in Jenkins. The *remote root directory* of my agent is set to my project root path. But when I test, where I am during the build (e.g. by defining a step like `sh 'pwd'`), I see, that the directory, my steps are executed from is the `$WORKSPACE` directory (`/path_to_remote_root_directory_of_the_agent/workspace/jenkins_project_title`). That means, I cannot just start neither my unit tests like `sh 'vendor/bin/phpunit ./test/Unit'`, nor other tasks, that I usually run from the project root folder.

I'm pretty sure, that I simply configured something incorrectly and that in the normal case scripts like [this](https://gist.github.com/Yuav/435f29cad03bf0006a85d31f2350f7b4)

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'devvm-slave-01'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Prepare') {
            steps {
                sh 'composer install'
                ...
            }
        }
        ...
        stage('Checkstyle') {
            steps {
                sh 'vendor/bin/phpcs --report=checkstyle --report-file=`pwd`/build/logs/checkstyle.xml --standard=PSR2 --extensions=php --ignore=autoload.php --ignore=vendor/ . || exit 0'
                checkstyle pattern: 'build/logs/checkstyle.xml'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

work as expected without any crude workarounds for paths.

**What am I doing wrong and how to get it working correctly?**

Answer (score 0):

From the section "[agent](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent)" of the "[Jenkins Handbook](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/)"'s chapter "[Pipeline Syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-sections)":

> **Parameters**
>
> **node**
>
> `agent { node { label 'labelName' } }` behaves the same as agent `{ label 'labelName' }`, but node allows for additional options (such as `customWorkspace`).

So, the solution is the using of the `node` and its `customWorkspace` option:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'devvm-slave-01'
            customWorkspace '/path/to/my/project'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```